# How to acces a file in App package for Windows store app

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am trying to access a particular file from my app installed package but im gettin Javascript type mismatch error. what am i doing wrong. Please tell me a good way to access any file from my installed package.

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appx://PackageName/images/appicon.png").done(
function (file) {

    // Process file
}
```

);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to create an `URI` from the string first.

```
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("ms-appx:///datafile.xml")
Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri).done()
```

[MSDN Link: StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefromapplicationuriasync)